# Setting up, Testing with compile-time Dependency Injection, with Playframework 2.6 Macwire

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest, macwire

In my project I have this structure

```
app/
  --> common/
    --> DefyProductsComponents
    --> DefyProductsLoader
  --> controllers/
    --> HomeController
```

DefyProductsComponents

```
  package common

  import com.softwaremill.macwire.wire
  import controllers.{Assets, AssetsComponents, HomeController}
  import play.api.ApplicationLoader.Context
  import play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext
  import play.api.routing.Router
  import play.filters.HttpFiltersComponents
  import router.Routes

  import scala.concurrent.Future

  class DefyProductsComponents(context: Context)
    extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context)
      with HttpFiltersComponents
      with AssetsComponents {

    // Controllers
    lazy val homeController = wire[HomeController]

    // Router
    override lazy val assets = wire[Assets]
    lazy val prefix: String = "/"
    lazy val defyProductsRouter: Router = wire[Routes]
    lazy val router: Router = defyProductsRouter

  }
```

DefyProductsLoader

```
package common

import play.api._
import play.api.ApplicationLoader.Context

class DefyProductsLoader extends ApplicationLoader {

  override def load(context: Context): Application = {
    LoggerConfigurator(context.environment.classLoader).foreach { _.configure(context.environment) }
    new DefyProductsComponents(context).application
  }

}
```

HomeController

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._

class HomeController (val controllerComponents: ControllerComponents) extends BaseController {

  def index() = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok(views.html.index("Welcome to Play"))
  }
}
```

I want to setup the test the tests, this is the `test/` structure

```
test/
  --> common/
    --> DefyProductsServerTest
  --> controllers
    --> HomeControllerSpec
```

DefyProductsServerTest

```
package common

import org.scalatestplus.play.PlaySpec
import org.scalatestplus.play.components.OneAppPerTestWithComponents
import play.api.{BuiltInComponents, NoHttpFiltersComponents}

class DefyProductsServerTest extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerTestWithComponents {

  override def components: BuiltInComponents = new DefyProductsComponents(context) with NoHttpFiltersComponents {

  }

}
```

HomeControllerSpec

```
package controllers

import common.DefyProductsServerTest
import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._

class HomeControllerSpec extends DefyProductsServerTest {

  "HomeController GET" should {

    "render the index page from the application" in {
      val home = homeController.index().apply(FakeRequest(GET, "/"))

      status(home) mustBe OK
      contentType(home) mustBe Some("text/html")
      contentAsString(home) must include ("Welcome to Play")
    }

    "render the index page from the router" in {
      val request = FakeRequest(GET, "/")
      val home = route(app, request).get

      status(home) mustBe OK
      contentType(home) mustBe Some("text/html")
      contentAsString(home) must include ("Welcome to Play")
    }
  }
}
```

This setup I wrote is not working and I am not sure why in the `HomeControllerSpec` homeController is not found. I understand that in the tests all components from `DefyProductsComponents` are available and I am able to override

---

UPDATE: I created a very similar project in github. Just in case someone want to play with it https://github.com/agusgambina/play-scala-base.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest to do here is:

in `DefyProductsServerTest`, change `components` into:

```
override def components: DefyProductsComponents = ...
```

Then in your test you should be able to do:

```
val home = new components.homeController.index().apply(FakeRequest(GET, "/"))
```

Comment: A.thank you for your answer, I tried that and the error message changed `Error:(22, 44) Cannot find a value of type: [play.api.mvc.ControllerComponents]
      val controller: HomeController = wire[HomeController]`. I will keep trying to find the answer.

Comment: @agusgambina, you just have to pull the dependencies all the way, updated my answer to show a simpler way

Comment: A.Thank you for your answer, it did work. I will look at it in detail now, because if this is the easiest way, I understand that there will be a better way.

Comment: With this new solution, I'm not sure there's a better way anymore. The previous solution created 2 controller instances, that's why it was not the best.